# Multi Jwt Auth with Laravel and Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I have three types of Authenticatable model and I need to have separate JWT authentication for each. Let me explain more about my issue.

I'm using **MongoDB** as my database and [Laravel MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) is the package that I use.

`User`, `Admin`, and `ServiceProvider` are my models.

To having JWT auth in Laravel I use [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package. It's ok with user model (collection). when I want to use JWT with any of other models It not work and do everything with `user` again.

I search a lot an I found out that to change the provider user model I can use `Config::set();` method like below,

```
Config::set('jwt.user', Admin::class);
Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', Admin::class);
```

But no effect on JWT auth. (I checked the value of `'jwt.user'` and `'auth.providers.users.model'` with `Config::get()` method and returned it, It has been changed to `'App\Admin'`).

Need to say, My codes are as simple as possible according to the documentation of the package.
Here is my `UserController` code:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors());
        }

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required|valid_phone|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors());
        }

        User::create([
            'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
            'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
            'city_abbr' => $request->get('city_abbr'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password')),
        ]);
        $user = User::first();
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ]);

    }

}
```

And my `AdminController`:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors());
        }

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        Config::set('jwt.user', Admin::class);
        Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', Admin::class);

        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        $admin = Admin::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        return response()->json([
            'admin' => $admin,
            'token' => $token
        ]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:admins',
            'phone' => 'required|valid_phone|unique:admins',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors());
        }

        $admin = Admin::create([
            'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'access' => $request->get('access'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password')),
        ]);
        Config::set('jwt.user', Admin::class);
        Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', Admin::class);

        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($admin);

        return response()->json([
            'admin' => $admin,
            'token' => $token
        ]);

    }

}
```

Am I wrong in somewhere?
Is there any solution for this?

**Update:**

To be sure about MongoDB functionality, I test all of above doings with a relational database, actually MySQL. Nothing changed!

JWTAuth generates token but when I run `toUser` method with any models except `User`, it returns null!

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `$admin = Admin::create(...`? I'm afraid if `Admin::first()` returns right user.

Comment: Oops! it was just a test. The right code that I used first was `$admin = Admin::creat...`. I will edit this. Thank you for your notice! @revo

Comment: Right, as an aside since I'm not sure about `jwt`, I encourage you to to use a fully qualified name for `Admin` model. Please replace these two lines `Config::set('jwt.user' , "App\Admin"); Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Admin::class); ` with old ones and recheck.

Comment: What do you mean old ones? @revo

Comment: By *old* I meant *current*.

Comment: It not work! I test it before :( @revo.

Comment: What data are returned?

Comment: Nothing actually!

Comment: You have three conditions one of which should be satisfied. So for sure there is something output.

Comment: You know, It was just a JWT on a `User` even on in other models! It return a token that generate on user model base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you must fo to add multi auth ability with JWT to my project.

1. In [tymon JWT auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package. In `JWTAuthServiceProvider`, Change `Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth` and `Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User\UserInterface` definition type from `singleton` to `bind` in `bootBindings` method.
2. Defined a new middleware and below code is its `handle` method:

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next){
           if (!$request->header('Auth-Type')) {
               return response()->json([
                   'success' => 0,
                   'result' => 'auth type could not found!'
               ]);
           }
       switch ($request->header('Auth-Type')) {
       case 'user':
           $auth_class = 'App\User';
           break;

       case 'admin':
           $auth_class = 'App\Admin';
           break;

       case 'provider':
           $auth_class = 'App\ServiceProvider';
           break;

       default:
           $auth_class = 'App\User';

   }

   if (!Helpers::modifyJWTAuthUser($auth_class))
       return response()->json([
           'status' => 0,
           'error' => 'provider not found!'
       ]);

   return $next($request);    }
   ```
3. Defined a function with name `modifyJWTAuthUser` in `Helpers` and here is its inner:

   ```
   public static function modifyJWTAuthUser($user_class){
   if (!$user_class ||
       (
           $user_class != 'App\User' &&
           $user_class != 'App\Admin' &&
           $user_class != 'App\ServiceProvider'
       ))
       return false;

   try {
       Config::set('jwt.user', $user_class);
       Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', $user_class);

       app()->make('tymon.jwt.provider.user');
       return true;
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       return false;
   }    }
   ```
4. Introduced another `$routeMiddleware` like below in `Kernel.php`:

   `...
   'modify.jwt.auth.user' => ChangeJWTAuthUser::class,`
5. and the last step, Adding `'modify.jwt.auth.user'` middleware to the routes that you want.

But even with this steps, You must have encountered a new issue. It was about getting the *auth token* by credentials in login and getting *auth user* from the token. (It seems that changing config value not effect on `JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)` and `$this->auth->authenticate($token)`)

**To solve the getting auth user from the token issue:**

Create a new middleware `CustomGetUserFrom`Token`which extends of Tymon's`jwt.auth`middleware, I mean`GetUserFromToken`and in line 35, and **replace**`$user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);`with`$user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);`

**And to solve getting the *auth token* by credentials in login issue:**

At first, Find the auth user and after that, check the user existence and valid the password with `Hash::check()` method, if these conditions return true, Generate a token from the user. Here is login code:

```
$admin = Admin::where('email', $request->email)->first();
if (!$admin || !Hash::check($request->get('password'), $admin->password)) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => '0',
        'error' => 'invalid_credentials'
    ], 401);
}
```

I'm not sure about this way but I think it's true until finding a correct way to do!

**Conclusion:**

Having multi JWT auth ability in Laravel perhaps have many other ways to do but I did like this and shared it to be helpful.

I think the only important point of this issue was `app()->make('tymon.jwt.provider.user');`, the ability to remake user provider after config values change.

Any other solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use just one model (actually table) for authentication. When you save user and admin you can handle it. But when a user has request with jwt token, you cann't know which model will return (Admin or User)?

Use only User model for authentication and Admin model extends from User.

Redesign database like this:

**users** table :  id, email, password, is_admin

**user_details** table : id, user_id, first_name, last_name, city_abbr, phone

**admin_details** table:  id, user_id, name, phone

Put this your **Admin** Model for overriding all queries:

```
protected $table = "users";

public function newQuery()
{
    return parent::newQuery()
        ->where("is_admin", true);
}
```

Comment: You say that I use roles, but is it the correct way? I already know about roles but in big projects that handles big data (like mine), it will cause some lags and also as I mention at top of the question, I have 3 type of authonticatable models and at least two access type for each. I want know more about adventages and disadvantages of this types of auth handling (roles). is it the only way? and notice it's possible to handle multi auth with multi models in relational databases.

Comment: and also in this type that you say, a token will be valid for each model!

Comment: The thing I want to explain is that you need to use a single model(table) to verify the jwt session.
For example, a user wants to list products and is using JWT to make requests. Which setting will you use  for 'auth.providers.users.model'   Admin or User or another one? You do not know anything except jwt token and you should to can verify it.
You can make JWT validity through a single model (table) and then get your  model it from base informations like email.

Comment: I write the correct answer below, you could read about. but my question awards will be yours. Bests, arkadaş ;)